# Desperately need Borland C++ library called cg16.lib

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I have an old project from the 1990's I desperately need to compile. The linker keeps asking for the Code Guard library cg16.lib but I don't have the install disks for this anymore.

Does anyone have cg16.lib?

I am compiling with version 4.5 of Borland C++. Its an ancient product but still works!

**ANSWER**

cg16.lib refers to a debugging product that measures memory consumption. So I figured I should be able to turn the need for this off in a project setting. However, after much looking, I couldn't see an option. So I did this. I changed the project type to dll, compiled, and then changed it back to the original project type and it worked when compiling. It was as though the requirement for CodeGuard was in the project and was removed when changing between project types.

Comment: Use an auction site like Ebay to find old software.

Comment: I've searched a lot on Google but cant find a link that reliably downloads it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought use of code guard would be optional. You should be able to remove it from the linker settings for the project and compile just fine?

Comment: Yeah, good point, I'll check it out.

Comment: Perhaps look for a -vG command line option, although I'm not 100% sure on that one.